# Simulate a real web page with jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I want to siumlate a real web page. On the server when the web page is loading images come slow. I downloaded the website i am working on eclipse tomcat server. obviously images load very past. I want them slow.

I tried Thread.sleep()

```
<div style="width:100px; height:75px; float:left" id="rsim"><a href="inc/6.html"><img border="0" 
 width="100" height="75" **<%  Thread.sleep(2000); %>src="inc/images/bo.jpg"**  /></a></div>

<div style="width:100px; height:75px; float:left" id="rsim"><a href="inc/4.html"><img border="0"  width="100" height="75" **<%  Thread.sleep(2000); %> src="inc/images/la1.jpg"**  /></a></div>
```

But it waits the entire web site 4 seconds then loads the site very fast.

Comment: You need something like this http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/image-load-demo.php ?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a filter:

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

public class WaitFilter implements Filter {

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // nothing
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // ignore
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void destroy() {
        // nothing
    }
}
```

Then, in your web.xml:

```
...
    <filter>
        <filter-name>WaitFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>mypackage.WaitFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>WaitFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
...
```